# Why do TensorFlow programs that use the GPU have a much higher virtual size than TensorFlow programs running on CPU only?

Tags: python, tensorflow

On my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS x64 server, I have 3 TensorFlow programs that run on the GPU, and 2 TensorFlow programs that run on the CPU:

```
 CPU%   MEM%  VIRT   RES   PID USER        NI S     TIME+   R/s   W/s Command
1047.3   0.1 11.7G 1.04G 29414 userli       0 S  34h06:03     0     0 python3.5 main_CPU.py
 930.6   0.1 12.2G  996M 28443 userli       0 R  44h58:36     0     0 python3.5 main_CPU.py
 162.0   0.1  776G 1.33G 27457 userli       0 S   8h09:06     0     0 python3.5 main_GPU.py
 144.8   0.1  776G 1.33G 20023 userli       0 S   8h53:24     0    4K python3.5 main_GPU.py
 144.0   0.1  776G 1.34G 20111 userli       0 S   8h48:52     0    4K python3.5 main_GPU.py
```

`main_CPU.py` is the same as `main_GPU.py` except that the former runs on the CPU while the latter runs on the GPU.

Why do TensorFlow processes that use the GPU have a much higher  [virtual size](https://serverfault.com/q/48582/126950) (`VIRT` column) than TensorFlow processes running on CPU only (776GB vs. ~12GB)?

Answer (score 0):

As your link indicates a bit, the virtual size is based on the virtual memory addresses allocated to the program and does not (accurately) represent the amount of data that is stored or used by the program. Virtual memory addresses may point to locations on the GPU that are 4 bytes each while the addresses could each represent 1MB on the CPU, thus inflating the represented virtual size by a factor of ~33.000 for those addresses.